# What does the notation $[\boldsymbol{A} | \boldsymbol{B} ]$ mean (line through a matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, coding-theory

I have just stumbled upon the following lecture slide, in which $G$ refers to a $k \times n$ matrix with linearly independent rows:

[image: slide]

What does the notation with the line going vertically down the center of the matrix denote?

Comment: It means that your matrix is built from two other matrices, written one after another.

Comment: Thank you. I don't suppose you know the code for this line in LaTeX?

Comment: The term for this is an "augmented" matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you're gluing these matrices. As in $$[A\mid B] = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{p1} & \cdots & a_{pn} & b_{p1} & \cdots & b_{pm}\end{array} \right),$$where $A = (a_{ij}) \in {\rm Mat}(p\times n, \Bbb R)$ and $B = (b_{ij}) \in {\rm Mat}(p\times m, \Bbb R)$. You can write it like that in $\LaTeX$ using the `array` environment. And of course you can use any ring $R$ instead of the reals $\Bbb R$ for the entries of the augmented matrix.

---

```
[A\mid B] = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} &
 b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots &
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
a_{p1} & \cdots & a_{pn} & 
b_{p1} & \cdots & b_{pm}
\end{array} \right)
```

Comment: Is "glue" the most recognized term for this operator?

Comment: Most probably not, I used the term very loosely back then. Something like "concatenation" should be more appropriate, or then saying that "$[A|B]$ is obtained by augmenting $A$ with $B$".